# Ubuntu. Ada Install AWS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ada

It is not fully established, in what could be the problem?

/usr/gnat/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/ld: cannot find -lldap
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gprlib: /usr/gnat/bin/gcc execution error
gprbuild: could not build library for project src
make: *** [build-native] Ошибка 4

.bashrc
PATH=/usr/gnat/bin:$PATH
export PATH

GPR_PROJECT_PATH=/usr/gnat/lib/gnat
export GPR_PROJECT_PATH

ADA_PROJECT_PATH=/usr/gnat/lib/gnat
export ADA_PROJECT_PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker cannot find the libldap library your program needs. Either it is not installed, or installed in the wrong place, or (on Debian/Ubuntu) the multilib build process is looking for it in the wrong place.

A possible fix for the multilib problem is to set LIBRARY_PATH to the correct value for your environment; here I run Make from a shell script, as follows:

```
# fix Debian multiarch..
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
make
```

I see you are already using LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but LIBRARY_PATH is a different variable.

Alternatively, if the problem is that libldap is not installed, the command (run as root or via sudo) `apt-get install libldap2-dev` should install it, then build should no longer have that error.

Comment: Is libldap installed? as in ... apt-get install libldap2-dev

Comment: It must be installed. How can I check?

Comment: Turns out he was just downloaded but not installed, after installing it worked!
THANK YOU! )